# Работа с char *variable

Tags: c, c++

Если `char *pStr`, то при обходе `pStr` циклом `for`, не записать ничего, выдает ошибку на `pStr[posTarget] = pStr[i];` Если выделить память при помощи malloc - ошибка пропадает, но символы меняются на неизвестно что. Может я память неправильно выделяю?

```
int length_string = strlen(pStr);
pStr = (char *) malloc(length_string);
free(pStr);
```

Comment: Вы правы - совсем все неправильно. 

**pStr у Вас не инициализирована**, содержит мусор (неизвестно какой адрес), ни на что в Вашей программе `pStr` реально не указывает.

@Владимир777, Вы русским языком поподробней опишите, что именно Вы хотите делать, с какими данными и откуда они в программе берутся.

Пока будете описывать (IMHO) сами догадаетесь, в чем ошибка.

Comment: Смотрите, у меня есть функция, принимающая параметром "char *pStr". Я просто объявляю в "main()" -  "char *pStr="AAA BBB CCC";", потом вызываю "RemoveDups (pStr);" ну а дальше работаю внутри "void RemoveDups (char *pStr)", выясняю длину для манипуляций через for "int length_string = strlen(pStr);", и все данные читаются, но не записываются. Как то так, выходит нужно не длину строки, а размер занимаемой памяти передать malloc?

Comment: Дело оказалось в объявлении, я думал память сама выделиться, если указать строку "char (звездочка)pStr="AAA BBB CCC";", а если инициализировать "char pStr[12]="AAA BBB CCC";", то все хорошо, есть доступ.

Comment: Память-то выделится. Под константу. А pStr получит адрес этой константы, которая в системах с защитой памяти размещается в read-only памяти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@Владимир777](/users/8899/%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80777)](/users/8899/%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80777), Вы в самом деле неправильно думали. (в комментарий не поместилось)

Когда Вы пишете

```
char *str;
```

память выделяется не под строку (неизвестной длины), **а под указатель (адрес)** 4 или 8 (64-bit CPU) байт!

Когда Вы пишете

```
char str[20] = "my string";
```

выделится 20 байт (char массив, в общем почти то же самое, что и строка), которые инициализируются (вместе с завершающим текст нулем).

Почему "в общем почти то же самое"? Потому, что можно написать

```
  char str20[20] = "my string";
  printf ("%s//%s\n",str20,str20+3);
  *(str20 + 5) = 'R';
  printf ("%s//%s\n",str20,str20+3);
```

и получить

```
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ g++ t2.c
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ ./a
my string//string
my stRing//stRing
```

а вот такая, например, запись не катит

```
str20 = str20+5;
str20 = "my string";
```

сообщая

```
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ g++ t2.c
t2.c: In function `void t()':
t2.c:20: error: incompatible types in assignment of `char*' to `char[20]'
t2.c:21: error: incompatible types in assignment of `const char[10]' to `char[20]'
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $
```

---

А в `malloc()` надо передавать число, сколько **байт выделить**. Если вы хотите разместить там строку длиной N байт, то надо запрашивать у `malloc()` N+1 байт.

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснения.

Answer (score 0):

Вы выделили память, но не инициализировали её. Используйте стандартную memset(pStr, 0, length_string);

Comment: @_mX, причем тут memset()? Он **length_string** по мусору считает.